# stage approval through API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-api

I need to promote to next stage in multiple builds (which are on progress) through approvals.

Is it possible to give pipeline stage approval through API in Jenkins using build numbers?

Comment: Is the `input` step not enough? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm having a Jenkins pipeline consist of 3 stages. For promoting to next stage, it need someone to approve.
The above pipeline consist of mulitple builds on progress.
If someone want to promote 8 builds to Stage3, They need to open all 8 builds and need to click 'approve'.
To avoid this repeated manual click, we thought to automate this by  Jenkins API. By sending build number to shell script, the script have to promote the above 8 builds by API.
Can I achieve this?